# Await execution of base method in derived event handler

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, async-await

I am trying to get file property in derived custom control. The code is follows:

```
    public partial class ControlBase : UserControl {
public ControlBase() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //Buttons
        PickFileButton.Click += pickFile;
}

protected virtual async void pickFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file == null) return;
    inputFile = file;
    }
}

public sealed partial class DerivedControl : ControlBase {

protected async override void pickFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        base.pickFile(sender, e);
        //need to pick file first
        var properties = await inputFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
}
```

How can I await `picker.PickSingleFileAsync()` completion? Derived implementation continues befor file has been picked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So which of these methods can you change? Typically, you do not override event handlers. The base class should have some kind of relevant event like `FilePicked` and possibly an `OnFilePicked` method that you could override in a derived class.

Comment: @mikez Any of methods. Thats not full implementation, just some example code for describing the probplem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you cannot `await` on `async void`, i suggest you do it in a way which is awaitable:

```
protected virtual async void pickFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     await PickFileAsync();
}

protected async Task PickFileAsync()
{
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file == null) return;
    inputFile = file;
}
```

And then inside your derived:

```
protected async override void pickFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    await base.PickFileAsync();

    //need to pick file first
    var properties = await inputFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
 }
```

I assume `inputFile` is accessible in your derived types. If not, simply return a `Task<InputFile>` from `PickFileAsync`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you lack await keyword in front of *base.PickFile(sender, e)* ?

Comment: A void returning method cannot be awaited.

Comment: Return Task then and use ContinueWith

Comment: You cannot change the return type on the event handler because that would make it incompatible with the RoutedEventHandler delegate type.